# What is size and volume in coinbase?

Tags: api, bitcoin, coinbase-api

https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-EUR/ticker returns something like

```
{
"trade_id": 437092,
"price": "363.76",
"size": "2.73207436",
"bid": "363.63",
"ask": "364.39",
"volume": "444.19694168",
"time": "2016-03-21T16:41:40.230529Z"
}
```

The [documentation](https://docs.exchange.coinbase.com/#get-product-ticker) does not state what these things mean.

My guess is:

`trade_id` is some kind of unique id.

`price` is the average price for a bitcoin to buy or sell

`bid` is the max amount that someone is willing to get

`ask` is the lowest amount that someone is willing pay

`time` is the timestamp of the request

Questions:

- I have no idea about `size` and am not really sure about volume. What are they?
- Why is everything returned in strings and not in floats?
- is the trade_id just an incrementor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Snapshot information about the last trade (tick), best bid/ask and 24h volume."

The size its the amount transfered on the last trade.

The volume its the total amount exchanged in the last 24h.

Why is everything returned in strings and not in floats?

Im sure that its to use a unique and type and also the most common for requests (strings).

is the trade_id just an incrementor?

The unique ID of the last trade registered on the last 24h